# SimpleDateFormat value insert to ms db

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I formatted my jspinner as:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner1, "MM/dd/yyyy");
jSpinner1.setEditor(de);
```

and try to insert the value of jSpinner to ms db:

```
String SQLString = "INSERT INTO Table1(DateToday)VALUES(?)";
stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQLString);
stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(sdf.format(jSpinner1.getValue())));
```

but I still get an error.

Please do me some favor if you could give any sample code to get it right.

Many many thanks...

Comment: What is the error message / stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server, you could use a string value

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
....
stmt.setString(1, sdf.format(jSpinner1.getValue()));
```

but the date should have worked so the error is likely that you have some constraint on the table that is not satisfied.

Comment: i formatted my ms db table as date/time with a shortdate format of 99/99/9999 e.g. thanks Richard btw...

Comment: i formatted my ms db table as date/time with a shortdate format of 99/99/9999 e.g. thanks Richard btw...